Largest sum of consecutive values in row, but is it still consecutive in the cell of the last column?
I have a row of non unique values in Excel 365, some cells are blank. I would like to scan the row and count consecutive cells where values exist.



W1
W2
W3
W4
W5
W6
W7
W8




1
2

1

1
2
3



So I've used the below array formula code:
{=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(H4:P4>0,COLUMN(H4:P4)),IF(H4:P4=0,COLUMN(H4:P4))))}

Providing the answer of 3: (W6, W7 and W8).
I would now like to use a new cell to display whether this consecutive run has ended in the last column; W8.
How would I write this?

What version of Excel do you have?

I've got Excel 365

Could try: =LET(a,SCAN(,SIGN(H5:O5),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,0))),INDEX(H4:O4,MATCH(MAX(a),a,)))

@MayukhBhattacharya That's very useful, I've just tried it now. It displays the column name where the large consecutive row ends, thanks!

Try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell H7
=LET(a,SCAN(,SIGN(H5:O5),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,0))),XLOOKUP(MAX(a),a,H4:O4,""))


Or, as commented above:
=LET(a,SCAN(,SIGN(H5:O5),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,0))),INDEX(H4:O4,MATCH(MAX(a),a,)))


As suggested by Tom Sir, if there are two runs of three and want to see if one of them finishes in the last place, then the following formula should be applied.
=LET(a,SCAN(,SIGN(H5:O5),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,0))),XLOOKUP(MAX(a),a,H4:O4,"",,-1))



Nice. I guess you might consider this for the case where there are two runs of three and you want to see if one of them finishes in the last place =LET(a,SCAN(,SIGN(H5:O5),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,0))),XLOOKUP(MAX(a),a,H4:O4,"",,-1))

@TomSharpe Sir, you are right, I will update. Thanks for the heads up

Great. OP said "... some cells are blank...". Wouldn't ISBLANK(H5:O5) with y,0,x+1 be more accurate? Also, maybe consider the case when the max repeats itself and the last max includes the last cell but the lookup, of course, chooses the first one i.e. getting closer to OP's requirement "... whether or not this consecutive run has ended in the last column" something like MAX(a)=TAKE(a,,-1).

Wonderful, didnt thought of that way.

SIGN could be replaced with LEN to make it compatible with text also (not the question though)

You can also write SCAN() like below to count consecutive non-blank cells:
=SCAN(0,H4:O4,LAMBDA(aggregated,current, (aggregated+1)*(current<>"")))
To find the largest consecutive count, you can also use SORT() and TAKE():
=TAKE(SORT(VSTACK(H3:O3, SCAN(0, H4:O4, LAMBDA(aggregated, current, (aggregated + 1) * (current <> "")))), 2, -1, TRUE), 1, 1)

